# MSDeploy: "Leave extra files on destination" from command line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, msdeploy

I use MSDeploy to publish things to different servers during CI. When I publish from Visual Studio 2010 I have a "Leave extra files on destination" option, but I can't seem to find a flag for this functionality when invoking MSDeploy from the command line.

Does anyone know how to do this??

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For msdeploy.exe you need to add `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` to ensure content is not deleted. For more info on MSDeploy rules see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568992(WS.10).aspx.

Comment: if running this from a 'package' you can add it directly as a parameter to the generated CMD file - eg. `SPAHost.Web.deploy.cmd /t -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` (where /T is a dry-run)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to choose which dirs need to be leaved, you can read http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html